# Java accesing properties with same name in both classes

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, upcasting

I have 2 classes, A and B which B inherits from A.
Both classes have a property of type int called w.

In class A w is public and in class B w is private.

I made an object of type A using B constructor - A a = new B()

Yet when i tried to access B's properties i found out i can only access variables or methods from class A even though i made an object of type B.

I thought that this was only relevant if both classes didnt have the same methods or variables.
But in this case both classes have a variable named w yet i can only access the value stored in the A class. Why is this so?

class A

```
public class A {
    public int w;
    private static String str = "K";

    
    public A() {
        str+="B";
        w+=str.length();
        str+=w;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return str.charAt(w-2)+"P";
    }
    

}
```

class B

```
public class B extends A {
    public static int w = 2;
    private String str = "W";
    
    public B(int x) {
        w+=super.w;
        str+=super.toString()+w;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + str;
    }
}
```

Testing class

```
public class Q1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        A a2 = new B(1);

        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(a.w);
        System.out.println(a2);
        System.out.println(a2.w);
        B b = new B(2);
        System.out.println(b);
    }

}
```

Comment: Help us help you - instead of describing the issue, share a [mcve] that demonstrates it

Comment: When you call a method on a reference of `A`, say `a.doSomething();` the compiler will check whether that method is present in `A`. It doesn't matter if the object assigned is encapsulating that method, the check is done during compile time and the casting happens in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Since the type of variable `a` is [class] `A`, the variable can only access members and methods of class `A` (depending on the access specifiers) – even though the actual type of variable `a` is class `B`.

Refer to method [paintComponent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics)), in class `javax.swing.JComponent`. The type of the method parameter is `Graphics` but the actual type of the parameter is [Graphics2D](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) (which extends `Graphics`). However, in order to access the methods of `Graphics2D`, you must first cast the parameter, i.e.

```java
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
```

This is a fundamental aspect of the object-oriented paradigm.
Refer also to the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75082053/java-accesing-properties-with-same-name-in-both-classes#comment132497170_75082053) to your question by @ArunSudhakaran

Similarly, if you want variable `a` to access the `w` member of class `B`, you need to cast `a`.

```java
A a = new B();
if (a instanceof B) {
    B b = (B) a;
    System.out.println(b.w);
}
```

If you are using at least Java 14, you can use [Pattern Matching for the instanceof Operator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/language/pattern-matching-instanceof-operator.html)

```java
A a = new B();
if (a instanceof B b) {
    System.out.println(b.w);
}
```

Also refer to the book [Effective Java](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/effective-java-3rd/9780134686097/) by Josh Bloch.